# Content Types linked to Content Types

Tags: entities, nodes

Using Drupal (v7.22) I'm creating a site that lists different cars. The editor of the site wants to be able to add different stats to the cars. But they don't know exactly which stats they will need so want the ability to add stat themselves. So for example they can set up two different stats where they fill in values:

```
Content
  Content Type (Stat)
  Title = Stat A
  Default Value = 10
  Min Value = 0
  Max Value = 50

Content
  Content Type (Stat)
  Title = Stat B
  Default Value = 20
  Min Value = 0
  Max Value = 40
```

Then they can add those stats to a new Content Type that they have created. When they add a type of Stat it will include the Default Value but it can be changed:

```
Content Type
  Title = Car
  Stat A Value = 10
  Stat B Value = 20

Content Type
  Title = Lorry
  Stat B Value = 30
```

Finally they can create Content of that Content Type and the Stats will use the value for that Stat by default but they can change it. I will create rules so that the entered values must be within the min/max set by the Stat.

```
Content
  Content Type = Car
  Title = Car Name
  Stat A Value = 15
  Stat B Value = 18
```

Can this be done with Drupal?

Answer (score 0):

I'm hoping this answer works for you. If you're wondering if you can set a default value for a field in a content type when adding new content, the answer is yes.

Comment: I'm actually looking for the ability to basically set a Content Type as a field within another Content Type. Or something to that effect

Comment: Ohh, I think I understand. You mean basically like predefined templates of a content type? So if you had a content type of "Car", you could have a predefined set of values for like "Ford Explorer", "Chevy Suburban", "Kia Rio", etc.?